# How to display internet connection error after 10 sec?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to display an error message after waiting for 10 secs.

I'm trying to display an internet connection error message in my Ionic2 app, I want to create the countdown like 10 sec, and call an api. after calling an api within 10 secs if data is not loaded, display error message.

.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
 this._myservice.myservice(this.taskdesc).subscribe(data => {
    this.displaydata = data;
    });

        var callDuration = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#time');
        this.startTimer(callDuration);
    }

    startTimer(display) {
        var timer = 10;
        var minutes;
        var seconds;

        Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(x => {
            minutes = Math.floor(timer / 60);
            seconds = Math.floor(timer % 60);

            display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

            --timer;
            if (--timer == 0) {
                 console.log('timeup');
            }
        })
    }
```

what's the better way to do it?

Comment: When you call `setTimeout()` which displays your error message you'll get a handle back. When the api call returns it calls `clearTimeout()` with the given handle and returns the desired data. If the call doesn't return the timeout will be reached and the message be shown.

Comment: Do you want to check if the device is connected to the internet or just to call an api after a countdown?

Comment: if its been 5 seconds and i have not got the success message, then i want to show "something went wrong,try again later"  , this issue can arise if there is internet breakage on client side or even on server side...hope you got it, please see my code above